# Network Graphics card

Tags: networking, laptop, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

Is it possible to have a desktop with a good graphics card be used by another computer on the network while a person uses the desktop?  I am looking to by a laptop and I already have a very powerful desktop and it would be nice to be able to utilise the power of it while using a laptop.  I do not want to use a remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  Simply put, even a gigabit network adapter cannot keep up with the speed of powerful PCIe graphics card.  A gigabit Ethernet adapter maxes at 1 Gbit/s, while a PCIe x16 graphics card maxes out at 252.064 Gbit/s.

The only real alternatives are things that grab the display buffer and transfer it over the network, like Remote Desktop, VNC, Steam In Home Streaming, etc.  And under intense graphical load, you will see the lag of the network.